# High Apache memory usage when using Event MPM

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

With zero traffic touching Apache (hidden behind Nginx and Varnish) it's memory usage rises up to total 10 GB. It is set to use Event MPM.
These stats are when the server is almost completely idle:

```
CPU usage   0% user, 0% kernel, 0% IO, 100% idle.

ps faux | grep httpd
root      3385  0.0  0.0 112640   964 pts/0    S+   14:43   0:00          \_ grep --color=auto httpd
root       676  0.0  0.3 705268 29824 ?        Ss   Oct21   0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    2888  0.0  0.1 292972 14464 ?        S    14:33   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    2889  0.0  0.1 294148 14236 ?        S    14:33   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    2890  0.0  0.2 1321996 21216 ?       Sl   14:33   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    2891  0.0  0.2 1059852 21224 ?       Sl   14:33   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    2893  0.0  0.2 1256460 21220 ?       Sl   14:33   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    3262  0.0  0.2 1125388 21216 ?       Sl   14:37   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ps -eLf | grep 676 | wc -l
113 
ps -eLf | grep 2888 | wc -l
2
ps -eLf | grep 2889 | wc -l
2
ps -eLf | grep 2890 | wc -l
28
ps -eLf | grep 2891 | wc -l
28
ps -eLf | grep 2893 | wc -l
28
ps -eLf | grep 3262 | wc -l
28
```

In terms of configuration, not sure what is helpful to share. Event is activated and the defaults thread set-up (centos 2.4.6) in use. Having not used Event MPM before I am unsure if this is the standard memory usage or if it is indicative of a problem... it does seem (VERY)high...

If you think other configuration setting would be helpful place let me know and I will provide.